# AngularJS: Passing data to modal from list

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am currently learning how to build a MEAN webapp from scratch. Stuff goes quite well until this point but now i am stuck at trying to pass data from my list (ng-repeat) to my modal via ng-click=updatePerson(person). I have absolutely no clue why I can't access the data from the list. I tried like 20 variants to link the data between both scopes without any success.

This is my Controller:

```
angular.module('userCtrl', ['userService','ui.bootstrap'])
.controller( 'userController', function(User, $uibModal, $log, $scope) {
var vm = this;
User.all().success( function(data) {
    vm.users = data;
})
vm.deleteUser = function(id) {
    User.delete(id).success(function(data) {
        User.all().success(function(data) {
            vm.users = data;
        });
    });
};
vm.createUser = function() {
    User.create(vm.userData).success(function(data) {
        vm.userData = {};

        User.all().success(function(data) {
            vm.users = data;
        });

    });
};
vm.updateUser = function(selectedUser) {
    $scope.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/modal.html',
        resolve: {
            user: function () {
                return $scope.selectedUser;
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedUser) {
        $scope.selected = selectedUser;
    });
};
});
```

My angular-router:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/home.html',
    controller : 'userController',
    controllerAs : 'user'
})
.when('/users', {
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/user.html',
    controller : 'userController',
    controllerAs : 'user'
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

My list:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn-lg btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal"></button>
<table class="table table-nonfluid table-bordered table-striped" ng-show="user.users">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in user.users">
        <td><button ng-click="user.deleteUser(person._id)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button></td>
        <td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.mail}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="user.updateUser(person)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button></td>
        <!--<td><button class="btn-lg btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal"></button>     </td>-->
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--Create Modal-->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Neue Person</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="form1" ng-submit="user.createUser()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Vorname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.firstname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Nachname</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.lastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                    <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Person erstellen</button>
                </div>
            </form>                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#createModal').modal('hide');
});
</script>
```

And here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal-content bs-example-modal-lg" role="dialog document">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ändere Person</h4>
</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Vorname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.firstname" placeholder={{person.firstname}}>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Nachname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.firstname" placeholder={{person.lastname}}>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="person.firstname" placeholder={{person.mail}}>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
        <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Person ändern</button>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `user` you're resolving won't be bound to the view automatically. You need a controller to do that. You can use the code below, or you can use `controllerAs`, but you'd have to update the modal's HTML accordingly.

```
vm.updateUser = function(selectedUser) {
    $scope.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/modal.html',
        resolve: {
            user: function () {
                return $scope.selectedUser;
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, user) {
            $scope.user = user;
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedUser) {
        $scope.selected = selectedUser;
    });
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice approach. Works well!